# Passing a string containing HTML tags to a directive, tags not rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm passing a string to my angular directive. The problem here is that the string I'm passing contains some html, and obviously this is rendered as text in the directive output.

I've been reading a lot, but all the solutions I can find (and also on Angular's docs) rely on using `ng-bind-html` directive.

What confuses me is how to use in case of having a custom directive.

For example, my custom directive looks like this:

```
uxctModule.directive('toolTip', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      scope:{
         message: "@"
      },

      template: '<span class="infobox_container"> '+
                     '<span class="infobox_icon"></span> '+
                        '<span class="infobox">{{message}}</span> '+
                '</span>'   
    }
  }
);
```

...and in my markup, I'm inserting it like this:

```
<div tool-tip message = "{{toolTip1Label}}"> </div>
```

where `toolTip1Label` is a variable coming from the controller, containing some tags, and it's passed to the directive.

I'm really confused about how properly use `ng-bind-html` in this type of setup (or maybe that is not the solution to my problem). I have also looked if there's a way to user some built in filters to explicitly render the html, but it doesn't seem to exist.

Thank for your help, hope this is question makes sense, I'm very new to angular but thanks to your help I'm improving day by day :)

Comment: In your directive's template, try: `<span ng-bind-html="message"></span>`

Comment: @MarcKline thank you, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think it's far better to find an other way it's very ugly to pass html to a directive from the controller to a directive it's not the angular way may you can put a hook in the controller directive

Comment: @Whisher thank you for your suggestion, but the string containing HTML it's editable by the client, and he wants to be able to format a bit the things....

Comment: Don't worry sometime it needs do something tricky :) it was just to point it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` is what you need. Just include `ngSanitize` in your module dependencies and add `angular-sanitize.js`. In your directive you can bind the HTML contained in your scope variable using `ng-bind-html`:

```
app.directive('toolTip', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      scope:{
         message: "@"
      },
      template: '<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>'   
    }
  }
);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5SIwNHinoDN5sy17t3zN?p=preview)

Comment: thank you! it was easy, I was just confused about the setup, but this makes a lot of sense